# Android : How to Solve The Emulator Error While Installing on OCI A1.Flex

Tags: android, android-emulator, arm, android-sdk-manager, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

Context :

I am trying to setup android CLI-tools for android sdk in :
Oracle Cloud (OCI) Ampere 1 (aarch64) Flex Instance (24GB Ram 4 Cores)

In the process i was instructed to install some packages like

```
"emulator","platform-tools","build-tools"
```

All other packages install properly but this one gives the following error .

```
./sdkmanager "emulator"
Warning: Failed to find package 'emulator'
```

As i am using OCI Ampere 1 Flex Instance , to use emulators , Arm translation tools wont be needed because Ampere 1 Instances are based on ARM . So android emulators should work easily but for some reason i can't seem to be able to install the "emulator" package for sdkmanager.

So if anyone has any solutions or any tutorials on using android-studio emulators in OCI- Ampere 1 , Please Share

*Note : I know Genymotion is in OCI and i can use that for android emulators , but its not available for free tier and it costs 0.5USD per hr , so its not a viable option*